# Scroll view not working with Grid view and linear layout

Tags: android, gridview, crash, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I've been trying to implement a scroll view into my existing code however when i attempt to do so, the app crashes. I have tried to add a linear view first, then the scroll view but i don't think i have done this correctly. I think there is an error with the layout weights but I'm not too sure. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <!--Row 1 -->
        <!--column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/colorTextHint"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ME"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row 1 -->
        <!--column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ME"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    </GridLayout>


</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ScrollView contains several children objects, but it can only contain one children object. However, these children's objects may in turn receive children's objects.

Hope that helps you and I have made no mistake now.

edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="23452345345edfsdf"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <!--Row 1 -->
        <!--column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ME"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row 1 -->
        <!--column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ME"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help however now my objects seem to have gone invisible. Any ideas ?

Comment: yea ... sry 
edit the xml file :)

you wrap the height of your scrollview, should be match_parent

Comment: That worked for the textView in the first RealativeLayout but didn't for the whole gridLayout.

Comment: Have the xml code updated.

No idea what it was exactly.
Maybe you delete this xml file from your project and create it again. Then you copy the code in. Hope it works now. At least in my current test, it worked.

Comment: But maybe there could still be a problem with the cardview? Maybe you use a different layout instead of the cardview. ?

Comment: I'm still having an issue with it. It doesn't seem to be giving me my 2 columns anymore

Comment: They still existed but had a height and width of 0dp.

Have the code adjusted again! :)
Have also added a current picture, as it looks like with me.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget.
Apparently, the scrollview also / had problems with the weighting of the elements.

Have these synonymous therefore taken out of the code.

Comment: Never mind, you're welcome! Hate that also creating layouts, is sometimes really complicated.